# How to automatize Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file, csv

I have an Ajax script who receive JSON data and convert them into a CSV file that the browser ask you to download when you run the script :

[image]

I would like to improve my script so that it would run itself automatically (like every hour) so that a csv file with updated data is generated every hour,

I am very new to programmation and I don't have any idea on how to proceed, do you guys know any tools, framework, languages that I can use for this purpose ?

Here is my script :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>This is Website Title</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../FileSaver.js"></script>
        <script>
            var formId = 566091
            // Définition des paramètres de la requête HTTP
            var settings = {
                "async": true,
                "crossDomain": true,
                "url": "https://www.kizeoforms.com/rest/v3/forms/"+formId+"/data/readnew",
                "method": "GET",
                "headers": {
                        "content-type": "application/json",
                        "Authorization": "*******",
                }
            }

            // Envoi de la requête et affichage en console de la réponse
            $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {

                console.log(response);
                var ronde1n = [];

                //on définit data qu'on va devoir parcourir avec un forEach
                const data = response.data;

                //on envoie les headers du fichiers csv
                ronde1n.push("Numéro d'enregistrement,ID,Date et heure,conso SSA3");

                //on parcours l'ensemble des enregistrements du formulaire Ronde 1 nuit
                  data.forEach(function (i) {
                     //on envoie les valeurs des champs qui nous intéressent pour chaque enregistrement
                     ronde1n.push("\r\n" + i.record_number + "," + i.id + "," + i.fields.date_et_heure.value + "," + i.fields.ssa_3_a_22h00.value);
                  });

                //création du fichier CSV
                var blob = new Blob([ronde1n], {type: "application/csv;charset=utf-8"});
                  saveAs(blob, "ronde1_nuit.csv");

            });

        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Something like this would only be possible inside a browser if the user keeps the browser window open

Comment: Put it in an interval?

Comment: TKoL, can you run this type of script using something else than a browser ? Or run the browser as a background process ?

Comment: Chrillewoodz, yeah but the thing is I would like the file to be automatically generated without asking the user, and eventually I would like the script to run as a background process not opening the browser every time